# Is routing the only way of passing data to the controller in ZF2?

Tags: controller, routes, zend-framework2

I’m interested in whether there are ways to pass data to the controller in some other way than through the router.  It’s easiest to express what I’m looking for through an example:

Let’s say that we take the ZF2 Album module and add additional functionality to the index template so that users can filter and sort the index of albums by genre, year, length, etc.  For this purpose, new columns are added to the table and filtering is done by select queries based upon parameters that have been sent via the router.  The following are examples of urls that would display different data sets using the same template:

`/album/jazz/1994`

`/album/punk/all/length`

`/album/rap/2002/tracks`

In the module, a user edits an album by following one of the “Edit” links in the index view.  Regardless of the index’s filters, the edit link url will always be something like `/album/edit/257` which tells the router to load the edit form for the album.  Both the controller and the edit view script include provisions for where to route to once the tasks or error checking is complete, and we have the opportunity to stipulate what that route is.

The question is, how do we get the controller to return to the same place the user was before editing an album or performing some other action?  If the user was at `/album/punk/all/length` before editing an album from that collection, we want to return to `/album/punk/all/length` after.

The coding in the controller is easy enough.  It would look something like this:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('albums',
           array(
               'action' => 'index',
               'genre' => $filter_genre,
               'year'=> $filter_year,
               'order'=> $order,
           ));
```

However, the controller doesn’t know where the user has come from, so the values for `$filter_genre`, `$filter_year` and `$order` are unknown.  I understand that one solution would be to configure the router for the action routes to accept all of the index parameters so that the sending pages could include “return-to” data in the url, but I question if there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the header **referer**. I do it this way:

All forms in my application extends a **FormBaseClass**

```
//I ADD A HIDDEN FIELD ON EVERY FORM
public function __construct( $serviceManager ) {
    $this->serviceManager = $serviceManager;
    $this->request = $serviceManager->get( 'request' );
    $this->data = get_object_vars( $this->request->getPost() );

    $this->add( array(
        'name' => 'referer',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'value' => $this->getReferer( $serviceManager )
        ),
    ) );
}

//HERE THE BAD NEWS, YOU CAN'T BE 100% SURE ABOUT THE EXISTENCE OF THE Referer, 
//IT CAN  BE  DISABLED BY USERS (SEARCH STACK OVERFLOW ABOUT IT, IT HAS BEEN 
//COVERED IN SOME QUESTIONS)
//IF THERE'S NO Referer, I REDIRECT USERS TO A DEFAULT PAGE DEFINED IN MY CONFIG FILE
private function getReferer() {
    $headers = $this->request->getHeaders();
    $referer = $headers->get( 'referer' );

    if ( $referer ) {
        $url = $this->getRefererUrl( $referer );
    } else {
        $config = $this->serviceManager->get( 'config' );

        $url = $config[ 'default_referer' ];
    }

    return $url;
}

//IF IT'S A POST, I ALREADY HAVE THE REFERER URI VALUE, SO I GET IT FROM THE HIDDEN ITSELF
private function getRefererUrl( $referer ) {
    if ( isset( $this->data[ 'referer' ] ) ) {
        return $this->data[ 'referer' ];
    }

    return $referer->getUri();
}
```

The only remaining thing to do is to add this input to your view. After that, you'll be able to grab it from your controller when you're finished editing your album.

I implemented it this way but I don't really use it. In the project I started using it, I ended doing the create/edit actions through AJAX calls with the list always in the background, so I don't have to worry about that. I suppose you can improve it and do it 100% fiable if you always post the current route through a hidden (carefully treating a first load of a page or a post).

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions for your problem.

**Using referer**

```php
public function myAction()
{
    $referer = $this->getRequest->getHeader('referer')->getUri();
    //sanitize $referer
    $this->redirect()->toUrl($referer);
}
```

**Using query variable**

Passing on the return-url by using a query parameter. So your edit-url would look like `/album/edit/257?return-url=<the-current-page>`.

In your controller your would fetch the return-url - eventually do some validation - and do a redirect.

```php
public function myAction()
{
    $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getQuery('return-url');
    //sanitize return-url
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl($returnUrl);
}
```

**Using sessions**

Safe the requests in a session so you know the previous request. The hardest solution imho.

Comment: The **referer** solution would fail if he loads the edit page more than one time. Example: click edit on an album from the list. The first time he's on the edit page, the referer has the desired value. If he does fields validation on server side, and it fails, the edit page is loaded again and the referer is lost, it's not the list page anymore but the edit one. That's why I do the hidden field stuff